# vb.net website and Inherits property in page declaration

Tags: vb.net

Today I opened a project I have been working on and then asked Visual Studio to open a page in Internet explorer. When the page opened, I received an error message, " Could not load type 'notitiae.from_sharepoint'". I checked and the page has the following page declaration:

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="from_sharepoint.aspx.vb" Inherits="notitiae.from_sharepoint" %>
```

I then found that if I removed the Inherits property from the page declaration, the page loads in the browser, but tosses an error in VS. It now appears that ALL my aspx pages need to have the Inherits property removed in order to function. This is weird as the pages worked fine last week.

Also: one of the pages is tossing an error in the related designer.vb page. it's telling me that "partial public class" --> Identifier expected. This does not make sense as the designer.vb page is autogenerated and has not been modified.

I think the problem began when I did a copy --> paste --> rename within the solution explorer. I was trying to save time vs adding a new page and copying the code from the other page.

what is the best way to fix this mess? 
How do I avoid this problem in the future? 
What is the best way to duplicate a file with a new name?

Mike

Comment: Back out your most recent changes?

Comment: I've found a solution to my problem but I'm not sure why it was a solution. 

The page that had the designer error, delete it, making a copy of the code to some place like a word document. Then add a new blank page to the solution explorer and add the code back in. This fixed the error message I had on that page and allowed the project to build successfully. I was then able to load pages in internet explorer without error. 

Can someone explaine what causes errors in the designer file when it's autogenerated? Also what is the best way to duplicate a file in an application?

Comment: After the site began to function correctly I found 3 pages that still complained that they could not load the item referenced in the Inherits property of the page declaration. For those pages, I had to copy the code to word, delete the page, add a brand new page with the same name and add the code back in. I don't see why I had to do this. Can someone explaine why I saw this behavior and how to prevent it in the future?